# How to list directories I have access to?

Tags: linux, permissions, directory

I don't know how to describe very well the situation. I don't have access to a directory, but I do have access to some stuff within that directory.

For example:
In `/path`

```
[me@pc path]$ ls
ls: cannot open directory '.': Permission denied
```

But I can still go into a couple of folders e.g.

```
[me@pc path]$ cd folder_1
[me@pc path/folder_1]$
```

How can I list all the folders I have access to? If I run `ls` or `find ./` I get `Permission denied` so I don't get to see anything, but I know I have access to some folders because I am able to `cd` into them.

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): [How to recursively check if a specfic user has read access to a folder and its contents?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/210093)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to get a listing without changing the permissions on `/path` or changing users.

In the UNIX file permission model, accessing the contents of a directory and listing its contents are considered separate permissions, with the listing controlled by the directory's `r`ead permission, and the ability to access files and folders under the directory controlled by its e`x`ecute permission.

In this case, you have execute permissions for `/path`, but not read permissions. This means you are not able to view the listing for the directory, but you are allowed to access files and directories contained within the folder if you have access to those. You are even able to create new files and directories within `/path` if you have write permission. But you are not allowed to get a listing of its contents.